# Shell script to show online users

Tags: bash, shell

I know it's an amateur question. I need to write a Bash shell script which count how many users is online atm at the SSH server. Tried with awk and rwho but i need to ignore multiple logins, and show the user name and the place where they logged in.

Thanks.

Comment: Show your attempted script.

Comment: This is a tall order.  I would start with the `finger` command to get a list of the current users and where they came from.

Comment: X=`rwho | uniq |awk '{print "User: " $1; print "Host: " $2}'` - but shows multiple logins.

Comment: @PatrikZelena why not putting this into the question?

Comment: use `{}` tool at top left for format your code. You need blank lines above and below. Another hint is `....|wc -l`. Skip the `X=` stuff until you're getting clean output AND input to uniq has to be `| sort` ed first. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This can be down with a simple awk command like:

```
rwho | awk '!a[$1]++'
```